# How to change element/range of elements in specific row?

Tags: matlab

I need to set all the negative elements of the first row in the matrix to zero,
and set all the elements between 3-5 to zero, and outputs the resulting matrix.

lets say my matrix is:

```
matrix =

    -5    -2     3
     4     7     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set negative elements in first row to zero:

```
matrix(1,matrix(1,:)<0) = 0
```

Set all elements on [3,5] to zero:

```
matrix(matrix>=3 & matrix <=5) = 0
```

Although you say between 3-5, which would be 4 and I am assuming this is not what you mean.

Note that for element-wise logical AND, you use `&`, while `&&` is used for a short-circuit logical AND.